# Downgrade Stripe subscription at the end of current period?

Tags: stripe-payments

How to downgrade an ongoing subscription to a lower-priced plan,
 on the day current subscription period ends, without using webhooks?
I am looking for a language-independent solution using API documentation.

Scenario:
Current plan: $100/month  Next invoice date: 1st of next month 
Desired plan: $50/month. Should be activated on the 1st of next month without proration.

Comment: Subscription schedules is likely what you're after: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules

Comment: Thanks for the comment Paul but I have gone through the documentation already, I am actually looking for a suggestion that maps on my scenario exactly.

Comment: If you want to downgrade a subscription at the billing cycle end without webhooks, then you'd have to keep track of when the billing cycle is due to end yourself. Stripe's solution is to use webhooks, so if you can't do that then perhaps something like a cron job will do the trick.